# Why transformer in deep learning is called transformer?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, artificial-intelligence, attention, transformers

Where does the name "transformer" come from in deep learning? I want to know more about the correlation between its name and its working principle.

Comment: Someone thought it would be a fun name...

Comment: Yeah, +1 to Tim. It’s marketing.

Comment: Probably because transformer architectures use series of (non)linear transformations, i.e., recall Q, V, K matrices. That might be the reason. @Tim yes fun name, if we associate with Transformers franchise. Interesting that name is not disputed by Hasbro.

Comment: But those matrix multiplications are exactly linear. There is only softmax function applied on the top of scalar products of K and Q and then again linearly multiplied by V.

Answer (score 2):

Transformer,  becuase it uses the attention mechanism with softmax transformation after  that using the feedforward with nonlinear transformation. In short it uses different transformations(activation functions) to transform the input from intial representation into final representation if  we would explain that in very simple words.

Comment: ...kinda like every other machine learning or even mathematical model